# Convert ui-select selected values to integar list

Tags: python, angularjs, list

I've used **angular-ui-select** that is selecting some IDs of int type like this
`9,2,3`.  I'm trying to pass these values as `integer` list to python file like this

```
param += '"lstRole":[' + $scope.multipleDemo.roles +']';
```

It throws error

```
Nonetype object is not iterable
```

and when I pass this param as

```
param += '"lstRole":"[' + $scope.multipleDemo.roles +']"';
```

it received as string list and throws error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Can anyone mention my mistake that what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

try this in your python function:

```
json_str = request.body.decode('utf-8')        
py_str = json.loads(json_str)

print(py_str["lstRole"])
```